# Github - How to show collaborate projects in my profile?

Tags: git, github

Somebody added me as a collaborater to a repository placed in his GitHub user.

Is it possible to make this project visible in MY github profile?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

When you click on "Customize your pinned repositories", it shows your repositories only by default. However, there is a checkbox available to also show the repositories you have contributed to. When you check that, they will show up and you can pin them.