# How to show repos I collaborated to on my personal Github page?

Tags: github, repository

I've worked on a project with a friend and we've used Github, but she is the owner of the repository, and I would like to have this repo on my Github profile too.

1. yes, I am a contributor of the repo, and,
2. yes, I've done lot of commits.

Google is not helping me, I have only found an old question about this topic ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38264220/github-how-to-show-collaborate-projects-in-my-profile)) but I do not find the button they are talking about:
[sceenshot of what I see when clicking "customize your pins"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/axznY.jpg)

Any clue ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Display a repository of which I am collaborator on profile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43407200/display-a-repository-of-which-i-am-collaborator-on-profile)

Answer (score -1):

Ensure on your [profile settings](https://github.com/settings/profile) you have checked the contributions section (it's below).

Also, you might be contributing to a branch so maybe the contributions will reflect after your friend merges the branch to the default branch

Comment: The OP was asking about having a repo appear on his profile, not making sure that he appears as a contributor in the repo.